# X,Y coordinates and centroid of an object after rotation - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am using this script to extract the X,Y coordinates and centroid of an object after rotation. The outline coordinates are saved in a table but when I scatter plot them in JMP I get another rotation (as shown in the image). Furthermore, I do not get the centroid. Any idea why and how can I solve it?

[image]

Code:

```
clc;
clear;
close all;
 
url='http://clipart-library.com/newimages/fish-clip-art-32.png';
I = rgb2gray(imread(url));
imshow(I);
rotAngle = 55;
I = imrotate(I, rotAngle,'nearest','loose');
imshow(I); 
           
[B,L] = bwboundaries(I,'noholes');
             
k=1;
stat = regionprops(I,'Centroid');
b = B{k};
xBoundary = b(:,2);
yBoundary = b(:,1);
centroidObject = stat(k).Centroid;
xCentre = centroidObject(:,2)
yCentre = centroidObject(:,1)
dataTable = table(xBoundary,yBoundary);            
writetable(dataTable,'E:/dataTable.csv')
hold on;  
plot(yCentre,xCentre,'Marker','x','Color','r');
plot(xBoundary,yBoundary,'Color','g');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code:

```matlab
stat = regionprops(I,'Centroid');
```

The input should be `L`, the labeled image, not `I`. If you fix that, you'll see that `stat` has only 1 output, rather than 255, and `stat(1)` will have meaningful values for your object, rather than `NaN` because `I` didn't have any pixels with a value of 1. The centroid being `NaN` caused no marker to be plotted.

Next, your plot is upside down because by default the image axes have y increasing downward, whereas the normal plot axes have y increasing upward.
With

```matlab
set(gca,'YDir','reverse')
```

after creating the plot, you can reverse the y axis of the plot.

Comment: I noticed that in some script xBoundary = b(:,2); while in other is yBoundary = b(:,2);. Which on is correct? I will appreciate an explanation.

Comment: @alirazi All you need to do is read [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwboundaries.html#bu1wval-1-B):  “Each row in the matrix contains the row and column coordinates of a boundary pixel.” That is, the first column is the row index (y coordinate) and the second column is the column index (x coordinate). If the description in the documentation is not clear, you can always check the numerous examples on the same documentation page.

Comment: The reason for the confusion is that xBoundary = b(:,2) and yBoundary = b(:,1) but as I understand xCentre should be centroidObject(:,1) and yCentre = centroidObject(:,2) following the documentation "The first element of Centroid is the horizontal coordinate (or x-coordinate) of the center of mass. The second element is the vertical coordinate (or y-coordinate)." Am I right or totally lost?

Comment: @alirazi Yes, you are right. MATLAB uses two different coordinate systems: when the docs say “i,j”, it’s matrix indices (row + column), when it’s “x,y” it’s graphics system coordinates. I find it unfortunate that this inconsistency exists, and that even within the Image Processing Toolbox some functions use the one system, and other functions use the other. The only solution is to look up every case to make sure you use the values in the right order. At least the docs are very detailed and always explicitly state which coordinate system is used for each function.